# Difference between ∀x∃y and ∃y∀x

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics

I'm currently reading this document by the University of Texas in Austin about Predicate Logic, and got stuck on the following:

Note about nested quantifiers: For predicate P (x, y): ∀x∀yP (x, y) has the same meaning as ∀y∀xP (x, y). ∃x∃yP (x, y) has the same meaning as ∃y∃xP (x, y).

We can not interchange the position of ∀ and ∃ like this! 
Example: U = set of married people. True or false? 
1. ∀x∃y[x is married to y]
2. ∃y∀x[x is married to y]

I'm doubtful about the answer to this example. Also, some explanation about ordering of ∃ and ∀ operators would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is by no means a programming question, but a basic logic / set theory question. Math.stackexchange.com might be a better place.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about logic / [math.se], not programming or software development.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1) ∀x∃y: For every x there exists a y (such that...)
2) ∃y∀x: There exists a y (such that) for every x...

Using the marriage example respectively:

1) Everyone is married to someone  (ie. For every person there exists a person to whom he/she is married)
2) Someone is married to everyone (ie. There is someone who is married to everyone)